# How can I validate that any attachments file name does not have ANY special characters in JavaScript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

By default SharePoint does not allow the following special characters to be present in attachment file names

```
~, #, %, & , *, {, }, \, :, <, >, ?, /, |, “
```

How can I validate that any attachments file name does not have ANY special characters(not just the ones above, but all special characters) in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Check below:[How To Validate File Names Of Attachments On SharePoint Forms](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/07/22/how-to-validate-file-names-of-attachments-on-sharepoint-forms/)

How could we validate attachment file names and prohibit attachments having invalid names? We can use the same method as described in my [former post](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/how-to-check-for-duplicated-attachments-on-sharepoint-forms/). We should update our onAttachOKbuttonClicked method with the file name validations. The new version, including the duplicate check as well as file name length and special character validation:

Source:

```
$(document).ready(attachEventHandlers);

function attachEventHandlers() {
    // override the default event handler with our custom method
    $('#attachOKbutton').attr("onclick", "onAttachOKbuttonClicked()");
}

function onAttachOKbuttonClicked() {
    var newFilePath = $('#attachmentsOnClient').find('input').last().val();
    // get the file name from the file path as described at
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript
    // TrimWhiteSpaces is a js method of SharePoint to filter out special characters from the file name
    var newFileName = TrimWhiteSpaces(newFilePath).replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    var maxFileNameLength = 128;

    // Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint
    // http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905231
    // http://www.sysadminsblog.com/microsoft/file-name-length-and-character-restrictions-for-sharepoint/
    // ivalid characters in SP:
    // ~#%&*{}\:<>?/+|"
    // ivalid characters in file system:
    // \/:*?"<>|
    // we have to check only:
    // ~#%&{}+|
    /*
    Cant be longer than 128 characters
    Cant use: ~ # % & * { } \ : < > ? / + | "; RegExp: [~#%\&{}+\|] – do not include characters that are not allowed in the file system
    Cant use the period character consecutively in the middle of a file name (blahblah.docx); RegExp: \\.\\.
    Cant use the period character at the end of a file name; RegExp:  ^\\.
    Cant use the period character at the start of a file name; RegExp:  \\.$    
    */

    var match = (new RegExp('[~#%\&{}+\|]|\\.\\.|^\\.|\\.$')).test(newFileName);
    if (match) {
        alert("Ivalid file name. The name of the attached file contains invalid characters.");
    }
    else if (newFileName.length > maxFileNameLength) {
        alert("Ivalid file name. The name of the attached file is too long.");
    }
    else {
        // it is the same duplicate check code from former post (https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/how-to-check-for-duplicated-attachments-on-sharepoint-forms/)
        var foundDuplication = false;

        $('#idAttachmentsTable').find('tbody').find('tr').each(function () {
            var existingFileName = $(this).find('.ms-vb').find('a').text();
            // if the existingFileName is empty then the attachment was uploaded in this session
            // that is, it is not saved yet
            if (existingFileName == '') {
                var existingFilePath = $(this).find('.ms-vb').find('span').text();
                existingFileName = existingFilePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
            }

            if (newFileName == existingFileName) {
                foundDuplication = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (foundDuplication) {
            alert("A file with name '" + newFileName + "' is already attached to this item.");
        }
        else {
            // call the OkAttach js method of SharePoint
            // this is the method that is originally called by uploading attachments
            OkAttach();
        }

    }
}
```

Also check this one [Sharepoint List item attachments validating](http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2014/09/sharepoint-list-item-attachments-validating-in-spforms/)